# cakephp 3.x _serialize key not working

Tags: json, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I an trying to return json from a cakephp 3.1 controller function.  My problem is that no matter what I do with the _serialize flag, the response is always that there is a missing view template file.

In the cake docs it says to set the _serialize flag if you do not need to use a template to format the response. [Cake Docs on View _serialize](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/views/json-and-xml-views.html#using-data-views-with-the-serialize-key)

Below is the Javascript on the client side that initializes the process

```
    function save_activity( mod, act, resp ) {

    $.ajax({
            method: 'POST', 
            url: '/activities/saveActivity', 
            data: { 
                'module' : "example1",
                'activity_name' : "example2",
                'response' : "example3"
            },
            dataType: 'json', 
            error: function( xhr, status, error ){
                alert( status + error );
            },
               success: function( data, status,  xhr ){
                   alert( status + data.success );
            }
});
}
```

The Controller code that handles the json from the client.

```
public function saveActivity()
    {
        $user = $this->Auth->user();

        //This line does not seem to do anything
        //$this->request->input('json_decode', 'true');

        //Debugger::log($this->request->data);

        $activityTable = TableRegistry::get('Activities');
        $activity = $activityTable->newEntity();

        $activity->user_id = $user['id'];
        $activity->module = $this->request->data('module');
        $activity->activity_name = $this->request->data('activity_name');
        $activity->response = $this->request->data('response');

        //These lines do not have any effect
        //$this->RequestHandler->renderAs($this, 'json');
        //$this->response->type('application/json');
        //$this->viewBuilder()->layout(null);
        //$this->render(false);

        $msg = '';
        if ($activityTable->save($activity)) {
            $msg = 'Activity Stored';
        } else {
            $msg = 'Activity Not Stored';
        }

        $this->set(['response' => $msg]);

       //comment or uncomment this line and it makes no difference
       //as it still returns a json response about a missing template.
       $this->set('_serialize', true);

    }
```

The error message I get when I include or remove the _serialize flag.

"Template file "Pages\json\module1\activity4.ctp" is missing."

Anyone have any insight into this mechanims? The workaround I have found is to include the template file... but this means I will have to generate a few dozen essentially empty template files to handle all the places this call is generated from.

Any help please?

Comment: The URL/action doesn't seem to fit the error message... it would fit to `/pages/module1/activity4`. So either you're doing some weird routing, or you're not showing the full picture.

Comment: I just had sample error messages in the ajax data fields while I was trying to debug the system.  I'm using a generic ajax handler and a generic controller action rather than duplicate all the functionality for many modules and many activities.  It all works except the _serialize flag does not turn the view template off as I understand it should.  I just want to generate the generic json response from the generic controller action rather than letting it fall through to the view layer which will result in many repetitious handler files all doing the same thing..

Comment: Thanks for the clue ndm.  Its not that the _serialize key is not working... its just that the 'saveActivity' controller action is not even being executed.  There is an issue with the AuthController failing and the call was being redirected through a different call path.  Progress.  Its always the unverified assumptions that get me.

Answer (score 1):

Problem cause:- Violation of assumption.

My assumption was that the saveActivity method was being executed.  While the reality was that AuthComponent was failing to allow access to that method and the default handler was being run instead, then the default view template was being looked for... and failing.

I found this by looking at the stack track attached to the error message in the returned page via devTools.  I should also have verified this assumption with some simple trace logging calls.  I already had the clue when I commented out the "$this->set('_serialize', true);" and nothing changed.

Then the simple solution was to authorise the method in the controllers beforeFilter:

```
  public function beforeFilter(Event $event)
    {
        parent::beforeFilter($event);

        $this->Auth->allow('saveActivity');
        $this->Auth->allow('getActivity');

        $this->eventManager()->off($this->Csrf);
    }
```

Thanks for the assist ndm.